# linux|awk|shell script modification of line with same name in many blocks

Tags: linux, bash, perl, awk, sed

```
My input file has blocks like below. 

[abc]  
para1=123  
para2=456  
para3=111  

[pqr]  
para1=333    
para2=765    
para3=1345    

[xyz]    
para1=888    
para2=236    
para3=964
```

now how do i modify the value of para2 inside the block pqr alone without the value being changed in other blocks or the first block alone.Please help me achieve this with awk or perl or sed commands.Thanks in advance

Comment: Some good solutions here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/137643/67817

Comment: `sed '/pqr/{:1;N;/para3/!b1;s/[0-9]* *$/newval/}' file`

Answer (score 1):

Try this `awk`:

```
awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '/^\[pqr\]/{sub(/para2=[^\n]*/, "para2=foobar")} 1' file
[abc]
para1=123
para2=456
para3=111

[pqr]
para1=333
para2=foobar
para3=1345

[xyz]
para1=888
para2=236
para3=964
```

Comment: Hi Anubhava ,
PFB the output for your command
bash-2.03$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '/^\[pqr\]/{sub(/para2=[^\n]*/, "para2=foobar")} 1' tmp.ini
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1

Comment: What is your awk version?

Answer (score 1):

I usually use something like this `awk` command:

```
$ awk '/^\[/{b=0} /^\[pqr\]/{b=1} /^para2=/{if(b) {sub(/=.*/, "=newvalue")}} 1' t
[abc]
para1=123
para2=456
para3=111

[pqr]
para1=333
para2=newvalue
para3=1345

[xyz]
para1=888
para2=236
para3=964
```

The idea is to use a boolean variable (here `b`) that gets set to 1 when we enter the right "block" and gets set back to 0 when you enter another block.

Then it's only a matter of verifying you're in the correct block in subsequent operations by checking the value of `b`, in this case replacing the value of para2. I also use this technique to simply extract one particular "block" from config files.

Comment: Hi Seco,
bash-2.03$ awk '/^\[/{b=0} /^\[pqr\]/{b=1} /^para2=/{if(b) {sub(/=.*/, "=newvalue")}} 1' tmp.ini
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line 1
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1
this is the error i am getting. Please advice

Comment: You need to make sure the square brackets are properly escaped with a backslash, e.g. /^\[ and not /^[ as you pasted

Answer (score 1):

With perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

#separate records with double line feed. 
local $/ = "\n\n"; 

#iterate stdin or file names specified on command line 
while ( <> ) { 
    #replace if the block starts [pqr]
    s/para2=\d+/para2=9999/m if  m/^\[pqr\]/; 
    print;
}
```

This one-liner-ifies as;

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN { $/ = "\n\n" } s/para2=\d+/para2=9999/m if  m/^\[pqr\]/;'
```

And gives (for your input):

```
[abc]  
para1=123  
para2=456  
para3=111  

[pqr]  
para1=333    
para2=9999    
para3=1345    

[xyz]    
para1=888    
para2=236    
para3=964
```

Comment: Hi Sobrique,
i am getting syntax error. Please see output below...
bash-2.03$ perl -pe 's/BEGIN { $/ = "\n\n" } para2=\d+/para2=9999/m if  m/^\[pqr\]/;' tmp.ini
Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "s/BEGIN { $/ = "\n\n" } para2=\d+/para2"
syntax error at -e line 1, near "s/BEGIN { $/ = "\n\n" } para2=\d+/para2"
Search pattern not terminated at -e line 1.

Comment: For some reason I lost part of the text when I pasted. Edited: `perl -pe 'BEGIN { $/ = "\n\n" } s/para2=\d+/para2=9999/m if  m/^\[pqr\]/;'`
 `

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -v RS=  -v ORS='\n\n' '/pqr/{sub(/para2=765/,"para2=new")}1' file
[abc]  
para1=123  
para2=456  
para3=111  

[pqr]  
para1=333    
para2=new    
para3=1345    

[xyz]    
para1=888    
para2=236    
para3=964
```

Answer (score 0):

I would only ever use Perl for this.  One statement to keep track of the current group.  One statement to skip modifications except for a particular group.  One statement to replace everything after a key= with a new value.

```
perl -i -ple '$group = $1 if /^\[(.*?)\]/; next unless $group eq "pqr"; s/(?<=^para2=).*/newvalue/' file.conf
```